# How do you find dependencies when installing software?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dependencies

In software installation tutorials, they always have a long list of dependencies. How do they find those dependencies?

For example, I'm starting on a fresh Ubuntu server, following directions to install rvm. They provide something like:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core libreadline5 libncurses5-dev libreadline5-dev build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libpcre3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev;
```

I just want to understand how they find all of those dependencies. Copy and pasting works, but I think it's more important to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually apt will do that for you. if you try to install a binary package that has unmet dependencies, apt will tell you which ones are missing and ask you for permission to install them as well.

most source distributions tell you in a README file what the -dev dependencies are.

Answer (score 5):

Each package comes with a list of its own dependencies. For **debs**, which Ubuntu uses, you can do:-

```
[andys@daedalus ~]$ apt-cache depends git-core
git-core
  Depends: git
```

The dependencies for a package are specified when the package is built. Some of them are specified manually by the **package maintainer** (the person who's responsible for building the package), and some are automatically determined when the package is built. If you download a Debian source package, and look in the `debian/control` file, you'll see a number of lines like `Depends:`, `Conflicts:`, `Replaces:`, etc.

So, back to the example - `git-core` depends on only one package, which is `git`. `git` is probably a metapackage of some sort, which in turn has a whole raft of dependencies, to make sure all the packages neccessary to run git are installed - not just to satisfy the dependencies of one package. If we look at the `git` package:-

```
[andys@daedalus ~]$ apt-cache depends git
git
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcurl3-gnutls
  <...snip...>
  Suggests: git-cvs
  Suggests: git-svn
  Suggests: git-email
  <...snip...>
  Recommends: rsync
  <...snip...>
  Conflicts: git-core
  <...snip...>
  Breaks: stgit
  Breaks: stgit-contrib
  Replaces: <cogito>
  Replaces: git-core
```

...you'll see that `git` itself has further dependencies. To complicate things further, there's different kinds of dependency other than just requiring another package to be installed...

- **Conflicts** - this package conflicts with another package, and you probably won't be able to install the conflicting package without uninstalling this one, and vice versa. In this case, `git` conflicts with `git-core`. On my box here, the `git-core` package is marked as *obsolete*, which is probably why this is listed here.
- **Breaks** - this package breaks another package, and installing it - although perhaps not requiring you to uninstall the package that will be broken - will cause problems with the software installed by that package. Again, looking at our example, the `stgit` and `stgit-contrib` packages will be considered broken once `git` is installed.
- **Replaces** - this package replaces another package, meaning that the other package is obsolete and can probably be uninstalled. The `git-core` package shows up again here.

There are also 'soft' dependency types, such as **Recommends** and **Suggests**, which aren't *required* by the package you're installing, but are **recommended** or **suggested**, as the name suggests. Once again, looking at the example, the suggested and recommended packages are add-ons to git, or tools not directly related that will make using it easier.

Putting all this together, the package manager you use will start off with the package (or packages) you've asked it to install, and will look up the dependencies for it, and then any dependencies for those packages, and so on. It will also check for packages which conflict, break or replace the requested packages or their dependencies. Once it's happy that it's found a way it can satisfy your original request, it'll then go ahead with the install.

Different package managers have different ways of doing this **dependency resolution**. `apt-get`, `aptitude` and `dselect`, for example, all essentially do the same thing but the way they make their decision differs. You may find that `aptitude` and `dselect` will happily present you with a way to install a package whereas `apt-get` can't.

If you're interested in knowing more about Debian packages, have a look at the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/), which goes over some of the guts of debs.

Comment: +1. Thorough, clear.